# calculation of summing the product of combinations

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^{10}\sum_{i=j}^{10}{}^{10}C_j
{}^{j}C_i $$
I tried to expand the terms ,but I can't put sum them to get a legit answer.

${}^{10}C_0
{}^{0}C_0+{}^{10}C_1
{}^{1}C_0.... +{}^{10}C_1
{}^{1}C_1 +{}^{10}C_2
{}^{2}C_1+.......... +{}^{10}C_2
{}^{2}C_2+{}^{10}C_3
{}^{3}C_2 +....+{}^{10}C_{10}+
{}^{10}C_{10}  $

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{10}\sum_{j=i}^{10}\binom {10}j\binom ji
&=\sum_{0\le i\le j\le 10}\binom {10}j\binom ji\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{10}\sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom {10}j\binom ji\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{10}\binom {10}j\sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom ji\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{10}\binom {10}j2^j\\
&=(1+2)^{10}\\
&=3^{10}
\end{align}$$

Comment: can you explain it a little.

Comment: @Boris - have added two lines. hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: NICE hypergeometric, HAVE ANY IDEA HOW TO SOLVE IT USING COMBINATIONAL ARGUMENT, tHANKS